# Convert df column to date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following sample data to convert to date.

```
data = {'Dates':['20030430', '20010131', '20190805', '20191115']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The code I am using is

```
df['Converted Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'], format='%Y%m%d')
```

it gives the following error.

```
ValueError: time data '2011-10-13 00:00:00' does not match format '%Y%m%d' (match)
```

I tried

```
df['Converted Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'], format='%Y%m%d%f')
```

which results in below error.

```
ValueError: time data '20190805' does not match format '%Y%m%d%f' (match)
```

Kindly help to resolve.

Comment: Try just `pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])`.

Comment: It gives following error.
`ValueError: mixed datetimes and integers in passed array`

Comment: your data (the real one, not the one one you have shown) contains multiple date formats, you have to unify them

Comment: @Husnain you have bad data in that column ,  might be in this format year-day-month?